# Hang up the http connection after some duration in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to write a program to get some json data from some existing services in nodejs. But by attention to real time conditions in my app I need to make sure that the answer preparation will not take longer that for example 2 second.
after that duration I want to cut the connection which has been established and give the client my data from my own database.
I have searched a lot but the only thing that I found was setting timeout for socket in http.request which is presented below.

```
var options = { ... }
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  // Usual stuff: on(data), on(end), chunks, etc...
}

/* This does not work TOO MUCH... sometimes the socket is not ready (undefined) expecially on rapid sequences of requests */
req.socket.setTimeout(myTimeout);  
req.socket.on('timeout', function() {
  req.abort();
});
```

The above code will be executed only when the server is not reachable or can not be contacted. But my problem is forcing the connection to be closed.
Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module a try. It is really great for stuff like this:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'http://www.example.com',
  timeout: 2000,
}, (err, response, body) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: It is not working for me! Requests still taking more than 2000 miliseconds!

Comment: I tested the snippet above with example.com. With lower values for the timeout attribute i got a ETIMEDOUT error, so it definitely worked (request@2.65.0 + node 4.1.1).  Without real code i can't do anything more.